# Bluebird promise list of files async and json

Tags: json, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I have a list of files containing json I want to run a compare function on against some other json.
I'm using the lodash, bluebird promise in a mocha test and want to ensure they are all run before calling done.

a snippet of code:

```
  _.forEach(listOfLanguages, function(lang) {
    var localeResourcePromises = {};
    localeResourcePromises[lang.locale] = fs.readFileAsync(filename).then(JSON.parse);

    Promise.props(localResourcePromises).then(function (results) {

        // validate all required keys are in the lang json
        _.forEach(_.keys(localResourcePromises), function(locale) {
           //call comparison function with the json for the file
           compareKeys(results[locale]);
        });
        done();

    }).catch(SyntaxError, function (e) {
        console.error("file " + filename + "contains invalid json");
        done(e);
    }).catch(Promise.OperationalError, function (e) {
        console.error("unable to read file:" + filename + ", because: ", e.message);
        done(e);
    });
```

but the localeResourcePromises entries has not the json.parse promise but the file read promise

Is it possible to have a 2 step async (load file, parse json) fill in a promise.prop set of promises that will perform the function when they are all resolved?

How should I construct it to support this most efficiently? I don't want to wait till all the files are read to start parsing the json and running the compare method.

Comment: If you're using mocha use promise syntax for your tests - not the old `done` syntax

Comment: Also,  the promises `props` resolves _are_ the "JSON.parse" promises, you're not even storing the readFileAsync promises anywhere you're immediately chaining to them.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I see, ok I thought it was using the 1st promise not the chain. My forEach is containing the props call but shouldn't

Comment: I did not understand that last sentence at all, moreover - why are you using underscore for things available natively? `_.forEach(_.keys(x), function(){..})` is just `Object.keys(x).forEach(function(){...})` without the library dependency.

Comment: good point removing lodash dependency and now using native. thanks.

Comment: To clarify the last statement above, my issue was the loop through all the files just needs to fill in the localeResourcePromises. So that Promise.props is only called once, not over and over.

Comment: You're welcome to post an answer describing how you resolved the issue :)